# How to append table after complate all ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to check domain availability with php and ajax request. Requests will be sent to "whois.apitruck.com" API like this: "whois.apitruck.com/domain.com".
For each domain, a request is sent. I want to append table after complate all ajax request but this not work!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var domain = $('#domains').val().split("\n");
        var all_suffix = ["com","net","org","ir","biz","info","us","name","pro","eu","in","me","tv","cc"];
        var counter = 0;
        var TableDataString = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive domain-table"><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Domain Name</th><th>.Com</th><th>.Net</th><th>.Org</th><th>.Ir</th><th>.Biz</th><th>.Info</th><th>.Us</th><th>.Name</th><th>.Pro</th><th>.In</th><th>.Me</th><th>.Tv</th><th>.Cc</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
        var domain_count = domain.length;

        $.each(domain, function (i, val) {
            //increase i counter
            counter++;
            TableDataString += '<tr><td>'+ counter +'</td><td>'+ val +'</td>';

            $('input[type=checkbox]:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                    var flag = '';
                    var suffix = $(this).val();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "includes/ajax/ajax.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {domain: val, suffix: suffix},
                            success: function (msg) {
                                flag = msg.suc;
                            },
                            error: function (err) {
                                $('#domain_tables').html(err.error);
                            }
                        });//end $.ajax

                    if(flag){TableDataString += '<td><i class="fa fa-times"></i></td>';}else{TableDataString += '<td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>';}    
            });//end get each suffix  
            TableDataString += '</tr>';
        });//end each domain

        TableDataString += '</tbody></table>';
        if(counter === domain_count){
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
                $('#domain_tables').append(TableDataString);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I am used a flag and check this after `$.ajax`. The display problem solved. But for each ajax request echo a new table, If that display one table for all ajax request. How to append table after complate all ajax request?! Another problem is that check flag does not work properly! why?!

Comment: You need to use `echo` instead of `die` on your php code.

Comment: Any errors in the browser developer console (Firefox or Chrome) about bugs in this JS?

Comment: @simbo1905 console display: 'Range.detach' is now a no-op, as per DOM (http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-detach).

Comment: @hamed `echo` not solve the problem.

Comment: @tdir Try to use `console.log(msg)` at the beginning of `success` event and tell the result :)

Comment: @hamed display this:   XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/whois/includes/ajax/ajax.php".    Object {suc: false}

Comment: @hamed jQuery.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.11.2.js:9210 jQuery.extend.ajaxajax.js:17 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.2.js:384 jQuery.extend.eachjquery-1.11.2.js:136 jQuery.fn.jQuery.eachajax.js:14 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.2.js:384 jQuery.extend.eachajax.js:9 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.2.js:4665 jQuery.event.dispatchjquery-1.11.2.js:4333 jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle

Comment: @tdir Ok, got it, I will post you my answer.

Comment: see this pic [link](http://www.uppic.com/uploads/14258354511.jpg) why echo out of table?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're using `.append()` on your `$('#domain_tables')`, so that each time a new table is generated. You should empty the `#domain_tables` div before making another AJAX request(s) queue.
2. You're not checking which check-boxes are checked and which are not, so that you only create `<td>` elements for `chechbox:checked`.
3. Even if you add all necessary `<td>` elements, these generated in AJAX `success` callback will be added at the end of the table, because your loop runs faster than AJAX request (simply saying). You have to state which `<td>` element belong to which AJAX request.

---

I'd go this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {

        // check if anything is selected:
        if(!$('#domains').val() || !$('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length){
            return false;
        }
        // disable the button:
        var btn = $(this).prop('disabled', true);

        var domain = $('#domains').val().split("\n");
        var counter = 0;
        // an indicator to state when the button should be enabled again:
        var ajaxQueue = 0;
        var Table = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive domain-table"><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Domain Name</th><th>.Com</th><th>.Net</th><th>.Org</th><th>.Ir</th><th>.Biz</th><th>.Info</th><th>.Us</th><th>.Name</th><th>.Pro</th><th>.Eu</th><th>.In</th><th>.Me</th><th>.Tv</th><th>.Cc</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

        // create the td elements, but do not perform AJAX requests there:
        $.each(domain, function (i, val) {
            counter++;
            Table += '<tr><td>'+ counter +'</td><td>'+ val +'</td>';
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    ajaxQueue++;
                    // if checkbox is checked make td element with specified values and a "load-me" class:
                    Table += '<td class="load-me" data-domain="'+val+'" data-suffix="'+$(this).val()+'"><small>loading...</small></td>';
                }else{
                    Table += '<td><span class=text-muted><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span></td>';
                }
            });
            Table += '</tr>';
        });

        // Replace HTML of the 'domain_tables' div and perform AJAX request for each td element with "load-me" class:
        $('#domain_tables').html(Table+'</tbody></table>').find('td.load-me').each(function(){
            var td = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/ajax/ajax.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {domain: td.attr('data-domain'), suffix: td.attr('data-suffix')},
                success: function (msg) {
                    // decrease ajaxQueue and if it's 0 enable button again:
                    ajaxQueue--
                    if(ajaxQueue === 0){
                        btn.prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                    if(msg.suc == false){
                        td.html('<span class=text-danger><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>');
                    }else{
                        td.html('<span class=text-success><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>');
                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    $('#domain_tables').html(err.error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. chrom Console display this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function) - jQuery.event.dispatch - elemData.handle

Comment: mu php code is: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $domain = $_POST['domain'];
    $suffixes = $_POST['suffix'];
    $target = 'http://whois.apitruck.com/'.$domain.".".$suffixes;
    $getcontent = file_get_contents($target);
    $json = json_decode($getcontent);
    $status = $json->response->registered;
    if($status){
        die(json_encode(array('suc'=>true)));
    } else {
        die(json_encode(array('suc'=>false)));
    }
}

Comment: Do I need to change my PHP?

Comment: @tdir , No. What version of jQuery?

Comment: it should work without any problem. Note that I have removed `var all_suffix =...` from the code, perhaps you need it later on? What line of code the error points?

Comment: I do not need it. The error line is 4 `var btn = $(this).button('loading');`. When i chage this line to comment, the table will be created and domains correctly checked. but console display this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: btn is not defined`

Comment: Updated answer. Changed it to  `var btn = $(this).prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: I am using the Bootstrap. how can i make another page after filling 100 rows in the current page? (Pagination)

Comment: What do you mean *page*?

Comment: That mean is Pagination

Comment: it will require more processing and dependencies. It's a new question.

Comment: Correct to say. I mention one other question. I will appreciate if you tell us about it.

Comment: New question link: [How to create pagination of table rows more of 100](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931633/how-to-create-pagination-of-table-rows-more-of-100)

Comment: Please see this demo: [demo](http://totaldesign.ir/demo/11/) The code does not work properly

Comment: The last request is not sent. The button is not activated

Comment: Because You did not updated the whole code that I have edited last time.

Comment: Excuse me. It was wrong of me. Many thanks to my dear friend.

Comment: Hi, I checked 6000 domains (2000 rows * 3 suffix) and this script not work currently. why?

Comment: In the first time display table of domains but after a few second table removed and code not display result! Chrom console display this error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72581/discussion-between-tdir-and-artur-filipiak).

Answer (score 0):

My final answer is look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var domain = $('#domains').val().split("\n");
    var all_suffix = ["com","net","org","ir","biz","info","us","name","pro","eu","in","me","tv","cc"];
    var counter = 0;
    var TableDataString = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive domain-table"><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Domain Name</th><th>.Com</th><th>.Net</th><th>.Org</th><th>.Ir</th><th>.Biz</th><th>.Info</th><th>.Us</th><th>.Name</th><th>.Pro</th><th>.In</th><th>.Me</th><th>.Tv</th><th>.Cc</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
    var domain_count = domain.length;

    $.each(domain, function (i, val) {
        //increase i counter
        counter++;
        TableDataString += '<tr><td>'+ counter +'</td><td>'+ val +'</td>';

        $('input[type=checkbox]:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                var flag = false;
                var suffix = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "includes/ajax/ajax.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {domain: val, suffix: suffix},
                        success: function (msg) {
                            flag = msg.suc;
                            if(flag){TableDataString += '<td><i class="fa fa-times"></i></td>';}else{TableDataString += '<td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>';}  
                            TableDataString += '</tr>';
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            $('#domain_tables').html(err.error);
                        }
                    });//end $.ajax


        });//end get each suffix  

    });//end each domain


    if(counter === domain_count){
        TableDataString += '</tbody></table>';
        $('#domain_tables').append(TableDataString);
    }
});
```

});

I think this will solve your last two mentioned problem.

Comment: By this code console display: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o. and using this code table to Could not create

Comment: In this case, each suffix a row published! If i need to print a row for each domain

Comment: How can I print the table after all the ajax requests? I am using `ajaxComplete`. Now the table is created for each request! If that a table must be created for all request.